# Does the Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) block threads during WCF operations?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous

I'm working on an application that is going to be highly threaded, and our server calls are using WCF using the APM pattern.

We aren't going to be using .Net 4.5.1 so I can't use `async/await` with TPL. I'm ultimately trying to figure out if still using TPL (with `Task.Factory.FromAsync()`) will be beneficial over APM.

Does the APM pattern block threads when it's waiting on a return from the network from a WCF operation?

Edit: Code sample

```
public void DoSomething()
{
  IWcfServiceAgentAsync agent = new WcfServiceAgentProxy();

  var request = new DoSomethingRequest();

  agent.BeginDoSomething(request,
    iar =>
    { 
      var response = agent.EndDoSomething(iar);

      /*
       * Marshal back on to UI thread with results
       */
    }, null);
}
```

Comment: Calling `EndYourWcfFunction(asyncResult)` will block a thread if you do it. So it depends on how you are calling the functions. We don't need code of the WCF proxy itself but a example of how you plan on using the proxy. **Edit**: I have removed my old non relevent comments, please remove yours too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've modified my question with a code sample, however, we use a custom proxy generator so I'm not sure how much help the code sample is.

Comment: @Cameron: Note that the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package enables `async` on .NET 4.0 for UI applications.

Comment: @StephenCleary Scott and I had sort-of this discussion earlier, but we removed the comments. I'm using VS 2010, and it requires VS 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code example you provided it will not block any threads. The situation that could block would be if you did

```
public void DoSomething()
{
  IWcfServiceAgent agent = new WcfServiceAgentProxy();

  var request = new DoSomethingRequest();

  var iar = agent.BeginDoSomething(request, null, null);

  //Do some other time consuming work that does not depend on the response.    

  var response = agent.EndDoSomething(iar); //This blocks till DoSomething completes.

  //Do something with the response.

}
```

Comment: I understand this. I need to clarify my question even more, however, I think it would warrant a different question.

Comment: @Cameron I think you are asking does a thread get taken up in the background in the time between `BeginDoSomething` is called and your callback delegate is called? The answer is "not really, but yes", it uses [I/O Completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx) to do it. Once the WCF is done it signals the completion port which then schedules the callback to happen on a Thread Pool thread. Read the blog post "[There is no Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)" It is about TPM but the same logic applies to APM

Comment: ... One cavat, I am not 100% sure about the *"Once the WCF is done it signals the completion port which then schedules the callback to happen on a Thread Pool thread.*". The callback may execute on a IOCP specific thread pool thread which is not part of the normal thread pool max thread count, but I don't know if this happens for sure. However I do know for sure that between the time the `BeginXxxxx` call finishes and before the callback starts executing there are no threads sitting in the blocked state waiting around.

Comment: That's what I was trying to ask, but I guess I just couldn't get the right words to convey my point. I asked this in a different question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134915/using-the-asynchronous-programming-model-apm-in-a-wcf-operation-whats-going). Thanks for your response.